# Calculating Confidence intervals in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate confidence intervals from a t test in R manually and I suspect the way i calculate them are off.

Here's how I calculate confidence intervals manually right now

```
library(broom)
data("mtcars")
a1=tidy(t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars))
mean_diff<-a1$estimate 
tvalue <-a1$statistic

#standard error 
sd1=sd(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==0])
sd2=sd(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])
n1=length(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==0])
n2=length(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])
#formula for standard error
stan_error=sqrt((sd1/n1)+(sd2/n2))
```

then I take the formula from this page about calculating the confidence intervals http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/difference_means.html

The lower confidence interval I calculate like this

```
lower=mean_diff - (tvalue * stan_error)'
```

and the result comes out to be -4.147333

But the confidence intervals of

```
t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars)
```

are

```
95 percent confidence interval:
 -11.280194  -3.209684
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, critical value for t is not right.

`tvalue <- a1$statistic` needs to be replaced with `tvalue <- abs(qt(0.05/2, 30))`.

Note its not 32 because we lose 2 degrees of freedom.

And you are missing `^2` (i.e. to the power of two) in formula for standard error.
What you have in `sd1` and `sd2` are standard errors so you need to convert this into variances.
So correct formula is:

```
stan_error = sqrt((sd1^2 / n1) + (sd2^2 / n2))
```

So the new code becomes:

```
library(broom)
data("mtcars")
a1=tidy(t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars))
mean_diff<-a1$estimate 

t_cv<- abs(qt(0.05/2, 30))

#standard error 
sd1=sd(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==0])
sd2=sd(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])
n1=length(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==0])
n2=length(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])

#formula for standard error
stan_error = sqrt((sd1^2 / n1) + (sd2^2 / n2))

lower=mean_diff - (t_cv* stan_error)

lower
[1] -11.17264
```

But this still doesn't match the confidence interval using `t.test` function because `t.test` uses Welch's t-test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test)
So your t-critical value under Welch's t-test should be

```
# Welch's t test degrees of freedom
welch_df <- (sd1^2/n1 + sd2^2/n2)^2 / (sd1^4/(n1^2*(n1-1)) + sd2^4/(n2^2*(n2-1)))
t_cv <- abs(qt(0.05/2, welch_df))  

# Recalculate lower confidence interval
lower= mean_diff - (t_cv* stan_error)
lower
[1] -11.28019 # this matches confidence interval in t.test
```

Comment: So what even is this t value or "t" calculated by `t.test` (I got -3.7671) if it's different than the `wtvalue` (I got 18.33225 )and `tvalue` (I got 2.098196) which are actually using the real welch t test formulas to calculate the t value?

Comment: t statistic (or t value) is different to t critical value. t critical value is for significance testing, i.e. benchmark. t value is your calculated test statistic to compare against the critical value. You can get t value by `mean_diff/stan_error` = 3.7671

Comment: I think it is the object name that is confusing, just renamed `tvalue` to `t_cv` (t critical value)

Answer (score 1):

A more generalized approach can be taken for limited size samples or for cases where an a-priori assumption of normality can't be made, and thus a sampling distribution model (e.g.student's) may not be available or suitable. [1,2].

Start by loading the boot R package (version 1.3-24)

> RStudio Session Information
>   Created: Tue May 12 10:20:56 2020
>   R version:4.0.0 Nickname: Arbor Day
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32

```
  library(boot)

idx<-c(1:32)


diff.means <- function(d,idx) 


  {   
    m1 = mean(subset(d[idx, 1], d[idx, 9] == 1),na.rm=TRUE)
    m2 = mean(subset(d[idx, 1], d[idx, 9] == 0),na.rm=TRUE)
    gp1
    ss1=sum(subset(d[, 1], d[, 9] == 1)-m1)^2
    ss2=sum(subset(d[, 1], d[, 9] == 0)-m2)^2
    m= (m2-m1)
    v=(ss1 + ss2)/(max(idx) - 2)
    c(m,v)
    }



d<-mtcars

mpg.boot<- boot( data=mtcars,diff.means,R=100)

vt0 <- mpg.boot$t0[2]/mpg.boot$t0[1]^2
vt<-mpg.boot$t[, 2]/mpg.boot$t[ ,1]^2

mpg.ci<-boot.ci(mpg.boot, statistics= d,type = c("all"))



mpg.ci$t0

mpg.ci$normal[2]
mpg.ci$basic[4]
mpg.ci$percent[4]
mpg.ci$bca[4]
mpg.ci$student[4]
```

With just 100 resampling rounds (R=100) we can see that the four methods yield lower interval values that are similar among them and comparable to the student's distribution method:

1. normal approximation:  -11.24714
2. basic bootstrap method: -11.70073
3. bootstrap percentile method: -10.82624
4. adjusted bootstrap percentile (BCa) method: -11.23585

The value of R is somewhat arbitrary and limited by execution speed requirements. Higher R values do not create new data. This simply shows how statistics would behave if a larger sample was available.

```
plot(mpg.boot)
```

[Historgram and q-q- plot of resmapled distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYzSw.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYzSw.png): Bruce,P, Bruce, A., *Practical Statistics for Data Scientists*,O'Reilly, First Edition, 2017, pp. 57-60

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) [confidences](/questions/tagged/confidences) [resampling](/questions/tagged/resampling)